# problem with overleaf compiling

Tags: errors, compiling, overleaf

when i compile the latex file it shows the reason which is shown below[image]

Comment: You're not showing any relevant code so we don't know what is up with your document. Note the free accounts are only allowed to have compilation take 60sec (I think). If you have a lot of tables formated by siunitx this may take too long

Comment: Unrelated those ``\\`` before the captions are irrelevant

Comment: Sorry you're having problems. In the red box at the top, there is a link "Learn how to fix compile timeouts." The article that this points to has some suggestions that may help. If you are unable to resolve your problem, please contact Overleaf support - they can take a closer look and offer suggestions (I'm a member of the support team at Overleaf).